# basic question about python for loop and enumerate

Tags: python

I am trying to build a function that will return the sum of the first item in the data list and every tenth item after, so I write the script below, however, the result is always the first data in my list. How should I modify my code and fix it?

```
def Sum10th(data):
  sum=0
  for i,d in enumerate(data):
    if (i % 10 == 0): sum = sum+d
    return sum

p = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
print(Sum10th(p))
```

The desired result should be 31, however the computer only returns the value of 1.

Comment: Your `return` is indented too much, so the return stops you function after the first iteration of the for loop. And you should be expecting the result to be `12`.

Comment: You could achieve the same with `sum(data[::10])`

Comment: Also, `sum` is a function in Python. Please, please use a different variable name

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
p = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
def Sum10th(data):
    return sum([v for i, v in enumerate(p) if (i + 1) % 10 == 0 or i == 0])

print(Sum10th(p))
```

Output

```
31
```

By using the list comprehension with an if, at the end of it, you can get all the first item with the tenth item following it from a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def sum10thdata(data):
     sum = 0
     l = len(data)
     for i in range(0,l,10):
        sum+=data[i]
     return sum
```